# Go intelisense and autocomplete not working in vscode

Tags: go, vscode-extensions, gopls

I have installed go in my mac. In vscode I have installed official go extension. But **autocomplete doesn't work**.

When I open a go folder I get this in output tab in terminal.

```
Tools environment: GOPATH=/Users/drexter/go
Installing 1 tool at /Users/drexter/go/bin in module mode.
  gopls@0.14.1

Installing golang.org/x/tools/gopls@v0.14.1 (/Users/drexter/go/bin/gopls) SUCCEEDED

All tools successfully installed. You are ready to Go. :)
```

`which go` gives '/usr/local/go/bin/go'

I didn't have goroot env variable set. So I set go root `export GOROOT=/Users/drexter/go/bin` in terminal.

printenv command gives

```
...
GOPATH=/Users/drexter/go
GOROOT=/Users/drexter/go/bin
...
```

vscode settings.json -

```
"go.languageServerFlags": [


  ],
  "go.toolsManagement.autoUpdate": true,
  "editor.tabCompletion": "on",
  "go.installDependenciesWhenBuilding": true,
  "go.formatTool": "gofmt",
  "go.gopath": "~/go",
  "go.useLanguageServer": true,
  "gopls": {
    // Add parameter placeholders when completing a function.
   "usePlaceholders": true,

   // If true, enable additional analyses with staticcheck.
   // Warning: This will significantly increase memory usage.
   "staticcheck": false,
  },
  "go.lintTool": "golangci-lint",
  "go.delveConfig": {
  
  },
  // "go.goroot": "~go/bin",
  "editor.fontSize": 14,
  "[go]": {


    "editor.insertSpaces": false,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
      "source.organizeImports": true
    }
  }
```

I also uninstalled and installed go extension. tried go nightly extension. None of them working.

Any Idea how to get go autocompletion working.

Comment: https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/issues is the place you should go to.

Comment: Try reloading VSCode window (Ctrl + Shift + P)

Comment: @ABDULLOKHMUKHAMMADJONOV doesn't work.

Comment: A side remark: never ever explicitly set `GOROOT`. As to your particular issue–I have no idea. I would try vscode-related venues to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I run Go in a MacBook Air and I have this config in my .zshrc file:

```
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go/
export GOPATH=$HOME/go/
export PATH="${GOROOT}/bin:${PATH}"
```

It works fine for me. But, these variables depends on where you have your Go installed.

Comment: I have a weired issue that it creates a go folder at usr/go. this folder doesn't have only a part of go files. when I delete this go folder intelisense work. but that folder is recreated when I restart my mac.

Answer (score 0):

It worked after reinstalling go